Python gunicorn worker vs a script
I need help in understanding this. Let's say I have a Python script on a server that takes parameters in and does some data processing. This script can be executed by any number of processes. Meaning, if there are 100 jobs calling this script with different parameters, provided there are enough resources, it just runs.
But in the case of web framework, we tend to use worker threads with utilities like gunicorn to handle concurrent processing. What is the difference between the first example and the second. Why do we need gunicorn in a web framework vs scripts just work for regular used cases?
